# Usage of "2>&1" in Command Prompt

Tags: cmd, command

In several commands in *CMD* I found a block of text written as **"2>&1"** ... No threads found here so just hit up idea of asking it.. Can anyone explain its *usage* and *working* please?

Comment: See the Microsoft article [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) which explains also this redirection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a redirection of the output that would normally go to STDERR - so, error messages etc. - to the target of normal output (usually STDOUT).

This is because output 2 is for error messages, the `>` is a redirect, and `&1` refers to the location normal output is being sent. It's used to make sure all messages from the command are in one place.

If you combine it with a normal redirect: `foo > log.txt 2>&1` - then both standard and error messages will end up in `log.txt`.

Comment: Got it.. Thanks.. 

Comment: No worries. Remember to up-vote answers that help, and click the green checkmark against one answer to "accept" it. :)

Comment: Can't.. I'm new here and seems lower users can't vote up or accept any answers.. (btw any alternative options?)

Comment: I believe you should always be able to vote and accept answers on your _own_ questions. [Help link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts)

Comment: NB: The `2>&1` must not appear before the stdout redirection, `>`. The stdout redirection can also be written as `1>`.

Answer (score 0):

That redirects STDERR (2) to STDOUT (1)

So all OUTPUT from STDERR will be available on STDOUT